# Css rounded images with border and some padding

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hope this image speaks everything...!!! Need to do this in html + css .. Note: I want the border inside the image.

Comment: No, it doesn't speak everything - what have you tried?

Comment: The round shape and the border is easy, but making the table and the floor will be the tricky part.

Comment: Do you really want the table and the floor style as css??? :-O

Comment: I want universe in HTML+CSS. hmm where did `<div id="moon"></div>` go?

Comment: Why down votes ? Hope the image and the question title is very much clear... anyways I enjoyed the comments.. thanks to all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSS:

```
#border {
    border:3px dashed white;
    border-radius:100px;
    width:184px;
    height:184px;
    position:relative;
    left:5px;
    top:5px;
}

#image {
    background-image:url(table.jpg);
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius:100px;
}​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="image">
    <div id="border"></div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Adjust the widths and heights as needed.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yGcFx/

Comment: @AnubhavSaini well, if you add a rule like `#image:hover #border:before { content:url(meowww.wav); }` in some browser you could make the cat _meowww_;)

Comment: Nice! Instead of "dashed" the border should be "dotted"

Comment: @AnubhavSaini `img{azimuth:center;elevation:higher;richness:20;}`

Comment: @Tobi I dunno, the OP's example border looks more dashed than dotted.

Comment: Thanks.. Is it possible with img tag instead of background ? Because the image is coming dynamically and I prefer not to write the inline css

Comment: Thanks Juhana.. Even though the border is not displaying properly in Firefox. Also I need to do add a label in the bottom.. how to do this http://www.uploadup.com/di-E6OY.png . I have tried a lot but not getting the desired o/p